# How to setup a POP3 receive location in biztalk reutilizing the same orchestration and pipeline used for a file Receive location?

Tags: sql, biztalk, pop3

I want to send emails with csv attachments and have them picked through POP3, mapped and put in an SQL database by biztalk.

I've a file receive location that picks a file.

Receive location properties:

[image: File Location properties]

Pipeline Configurations

[image: Pipeline Configurations 1]
[image: Pipeline Configurations 2]

I paste the file in the folder.

[image: File dropped]

The file is picked by biztalk.

[image: File deleted]

Logs showing the file being processed:

```
    Timestamp: 5/9/2018 10:48:20 AM Message: <ns0:Request 
xmlns:ns0='http://ABC.MW.BackEnds.sp_MW_InformacaoTransaccaoSQL'> 
<ns1:sp_MW_InformacaoTransaccoes 
xmlns:ns1='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo'> 
<ns1:codEstado>1</ns1:codEstado> <ns1:ficheiroNome>C:\XYZ\TransacFecho\NoErrors-
a.csv</ns1:ficheiroNome> <ns1:numLinhas>0</ns1:numLinhas> 
<ns1:Debug>false</ns1:Debug> </ns1:sp_MW_InformacaoTransaccoes> </ns0:Request> 
Category: General Priority: 1 EventId: 0 Severity: Information Title: Machine: 
CORE04 Application Domain: __XDomain_3.0.1.0_0 Process Id: 44997 Process Name: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\BTSNTSvc.exe Win32 
Thread Id: 952 Thread Name: Extended Properties:
```

The data is inserted in the database after being mapped.

[image: Data was placed in the database]

I created an email location similar to the file receive location.

Mail properties.

[image: Mail Receive Location properties]

POP3 Properties.

[image: POP3 properties]

Pipeline Configurations.

[image: Pipeline Configurations 1]
[image: Pipeline Configurations 2]

I test the same csv file through mail.

Mail with file attached received.

[image: Mail with file received]

Mail is processed and deleted by biztalk.

[image: Mail with file removed by bitztalk]

The error I get.

```
    Timestamp: 5/9/2018 2:39:47 PM Message: 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PersistenceException: Exception occurred when persisting 
state to the database. ---> 
Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.PersistenceItemException: A batch item failed 
persistence Item-ID c99ae447-8f55-4589-9003-012e6bc599ad OperationType 
MAIO_CommitBatch Status -1061151998 ErrorInfo The published message could not be
 routed because no subscribers were found. . ---> 
Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.PublishMessageException: Failed to publish 
(send) a message in the batch. This is usually because there is no one expecting 
to receive this message. The error was The published message could not be routed 
because no subscribers were found. with status -1061151998. --- End of inner 
exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXXlangStore.Commit() at 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.Persist(Boolean dehydrate, Context ctx, Boolean 
idleRequired, Boolean finalPersist, Boolean bypassCommit, Boolean terminate) at 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.LongRunningTransaction.PendingCommit(Boolean ignore, 
XMessage msg) at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.PendingCommit(Boolean ignore, 
XMessage msg) at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceContext.PendingCommit(Boolean 
ignore, XMessage msg) at 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ExceptionHandlingContext.PendingCommit(Boolean 
ignoreCommit, XMessage msg) at 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ExceptionHandlingContext.PendingCommit(Boolean 
ignoreCommit, XMessage msg) at 
Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.SendMessage(Int32 iOperation, 
XLANGMessage msg, Correlation[] initCorrelations, Correlation[] 
followCorrelations, Context cxt, Segment seg, ActivityFlags flags) at 
XYZ.Middleware.Core.Bts.Orchestrations.oProcessSelectorPublisher.segment2(S
topConditions stopOn) at 
Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions 
stopCond, Exception& exp) Category: Critical Priority: 4 EventId: 0 Severity: 
Critical Title: Machine: CORE04 Application Domain: __XDomain_3.0.1.0_0 Process 
Id: 44998 Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 
R2\BTSNTSvc.exe Win32 Thread Id: 5792 Thread Name: Extended Properties:
```

Edit1: I intercepted the message in biztalk obtained through POP3 by stopping an orchestration and compared it with the one obtained through the file location.

Email message:
[image: Biztalk message email]

File message:
[image: Biztalk message file]

The email has an extra body part, is it possible to ignore it directly in the receive location using the mime decoder? Otherwise what options do I have? If possible I would like to avoid editing the orchestration or adding a new orchestration.

Comment: Well, I have to point out again that this error message is not from the Port.  It can only come from an Orchestration.  Please update with the steps, 1-2-3-etc, the message goes through in you app.

Comment: It looks like the persistence error is happening in the Receive Port. Create a send port that subscribes to the Receive Port.  Enlist it but leave it in a stopped state.    Then check what the properties of the message looks like, and why it doesn't match what the Orchestration expects.

Comment: @Johns-305 I edited the message in the end. Added another test.

Comment: I would really advice against using eMail as a message transfer protocol  in the first place.  1) There are multiple different standards for attachments in emails.  2) It is insecure (from email address is easily spoofed). 3) It is unreliable (emails can be deleted by anti spam/virus software on a mail server.)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf The email server and the biztalk server belong to the same organization. And there's only one organization sending emails to this mailbox too. Simpler than creating an interface to upload the documents.